# Python: echo with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, echo, qsub

I am trying to assign tasks to qsub from a python script.

So far I have always been using such expressions for qsub submission:

```
echo "python script.py arg1 arg2" | qsub
```

I tried to reproduce this command in python:

```
command = 'echo "python sub_master_script.py ' + str(i) + ' ' + path + '" | qsub -pe make 5 -N Teaching_' + str(i) + ' -cwd'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(command))
```

Although `command` carries a command I would normally use, it is interpreted as a simple `echo` when I launch the python script.

And instead of starting a new job, I get this written in console:

```
python sub_master_script.py 0.75 /data5/bio/runs-galkin/Iterative/test_OTU.txt | qsub -pe make 5 -N Teaching_0.75 -cwd
```

Why this happens? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're making heavy use of shell features, mostly by running 2 process piped together.

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split(command),shell=True)
```

is a quickfix.

A proper way of doing it would be to use 1 `subprocess.Popen` instance, provide the input through `communicate` (to simulate `echo python ...`) and drop `shell=True` (using `pipes.quote` as Charles commented to make sure that the strings are properly quoted if needed)

```
import pipes
input_string = "python sub_master_script.py {} {}\n".format(*(map(pipes.quote,[str(i),path])))

p = subprocess.Popen(['qsub','-pe','make','5','-N','Teaching_{}'.format(i),'-cwd'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate(input_string)
```

Comment: This assumes that `i` and `path` are strings that don't need to be quoted/escaped. Using `pipes.quote()` to prepare their values would be safer (though, granted, the OP's original shell command is unsafe/buggy in the exact same way)..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy nice add-on. Edited.

Comment: I tried using your solution and I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input'`
Using `subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` works fine. I don't see what's wrong with `shell = True`, so I think i'll leave it

Comment: sorry, typo: `input` is meant to be `stdin` (I'm surprised it's not needed: "Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE."). It's better to leave out `shell=True` when not needed, less surprises in store.